# Объявление переменной в функции

Tags: java

Есть такая функция у меня

```
public String[] conversion_byte_2_string(byte[] _temp){
    String[] _temp_result = new String[16];
    for (int j = 8; j < _temp.length; j++) {
        _temp_result[j] = Int_2_Hex(_temp[j]);
    }
    _temp_result[4] = Int_2_Hex(_temp[4]);
    _temp_result[5] = Int_2_Hex(_temp[5]);
    return _temp_result;
}
```

Как-то можно избавиться от объявления переменной _temp_result? Хотелось бы упростить. Функция возвращает массив значений

Answer (score 1):

> Как-то можно избавиться от объявления переменной _temp_result? - да, а смысл думаете есть?

Дело в том что массив String [] все равно возращять, значит придется его создать при любом раскладе. А ссылка _temp_result пропадет все равно после завершения функции.

В плане упрощения можете добавить 4 и 5 также в цикл но исключив проверкой 6 и 7

Comment: пересмотрел много аналогичных примеров, думаю, да, вы правы